# Lyx - Pandoc: export master document to Word with child documents included

Tags: table-of-contents, lyx, pandoc

I'm working on my thesis on Lyx using the built-in thesis template (Resources\examples\thesis). I've tried exporting it with Pandoc but it's only exporting the text contained within the master document (front matter), the contents of the child documents and the Table of contents (shown in pic) are not exported

Is this working normally? Is there any way to export the full document?

I could export each of the child documents and unite them in a single word document but I'll be missing the nifty TOC

Thanks!
[image: All of this content in the master document is not exported]

Answer (score 2):

**Issue 1: child contents lost**

<kbd>File</kbd> → <kbd>Export</kbd> →
<kbd>MS Microsoft Office Open XML</kbd> → `.docx` file

<kbd>File</kbd> → <kbd>Export</kbd> →
<kbd>OpenDocument (Pandoc)</kbd> → `.odt` file

<kbd>File</kbd> → <kbd>Export</kbd> →
<kbd>OpenDocument (tex4ht)</kbd> → `.odt` file

<kbd>File</kbd> → <kbd>Export</kbd> →
<kbd>LyXHTML</kbd> → `.xhtml` file

At least all these exporting ways should produce a single document compatible with LibreOffice/Word **with the contents of the child files**.

If this does not works for you, search for silly mistakes (includes in deactivated branches, or inside yellow notes, contents that are in the wrong path, etc.).

If this not solve the problem, edit your question to paste a  *minimal* `main.lyx` file (note the *emphasis* in "minimal")  and a *minimal* `child.lyx` where the export fail to include the contents of the child file (and only show this issue). Please, do no show screenshots or code fragments, just the complete (but as minimal as possible) LyX documents (the format of these files is plain text, so once saved, open them with some text editor to copy and paste the code, not with LyX).

**Issue 2: Lost ToC**

I do not know if there are some technical difficulty behind, but I guess that ToC is not exported  in DOCX and ODT fomats as pagination very probably will change, and therefore maintain the old ToC with the wrong pages have not munch sense.

Moreover, as headers are exported as true Word headers (not only large bold texts), and therefore recreate the ToC in Word or LibreOffice  automatically in seconds should not be any problem.

In XHTML export, there are no pages, so it is maintained a ToC with links to headers,  but obviously without pages, so this approach only have sense if you want to publish a web version, but to convert it to DOCX or PDF, better remove this ToC manually and make a new ToC using Word tools.